# searching annotations within kubernetes controllers

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

I was trying to find annotations to do some basic auth in Nginx controller.
Most of the resources on the internet specify this annotation:
"nginx.ingress.kuberenetes.io/..."

While I found that in the nginx docs:
https://docs.nginx.com/nginx-ingress-controller/configuration/ingress-resources/advanced-configuration-with-annotations/
It was switched to "nginx.org"

Searching external docs for answers seems a bit of a detour.
Is there a way to browse what annotations are supported on a contoller with local commands, maybe something similar to kubectl explain?

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

you can use `kubectl explain ingress`, but it will just show documentation about Kubernetes resources about ingress, something like

```
KIND:     Ingress
VERSION:  networking.k8s.io/v1

DESCRIPTION:
     Ingress is a collection of rules that allow inbound connections to reach
     the endpoints defined by a backend. An Ingress can be configured to give
     services externally-reachable urls, load balance traffic, terminate SSL,
     offer name based virtual hosting etc.

FIELDS:
   apiVersion   <string>
     APIVersion defines the versioned schema of this representation of an
     object. Servers should convert recognized schemas to the latest internal
     value, and may reject unrecognized values. More info:
     https://git.k8s.io/community/contributors/devel/sig-architecture/api-conventions.md#resources

   kind <string>
     Kind is a string value representing the REST resource this object
     represents. Servers may infer this from the endpoint the client submits
     requests to. Cannot be updated. In CamelCase. More info:
     https://git.k8s.io/community/contributors/devel/sig-architecture/api-conventions.md#types-kinds

   metadata <Object>
     Standard object's metadata. More info:
     https://git.k8s.io/community/contributors/devel/sig-architecture/api-conventions.md#metadata

   spec <Object>
     Spec is the desired state of the Ingress. More info:
     https://git.k8s.io/community/contributors/devel/sig-architecture/api-conventions.md#spec-and-status

   status   <Object>
     Status is the current state of the Ingress. More info:
     https://git.k8s.io/community/contributors/devel/sig-architecture/api-conventions.md#spec-and-status
```

In short, for annotation better to check helm-chart and official documentation

This how you can add basic auth to the ingress

Frist, create basic auth secret

```
htpasswd -c auth admin
kubectl create secret generic basic-auth --from-file=auth
```

then refer to this secret in the annotation

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-type: basic
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-secret: basic-auth
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-realm: 'Authentication Required to access Linkerd'
  name: linker-basicauth-ingress
  namespace: linkerd-viz
spec:
  tls:
    - hosts:
        - mybasic-auth.example.com
      secretName: ingres-tls-secret
  rules:
    - host: mybasic-auth.example.com
      http:
        paths:
          - backend:
              service:
                name: web
                port:
                  number:  8084
            path: /
            pathType: Prefix
```

[nginx-configuration/annotations.md](https://github.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/blob/main/docs/user-guide/nginx-configuration/annotations.md)